# How can i create check function in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to check in the table "PRENOTAZIONE" that the number of adults "n_adulti" is greater than 0 and less than max number of adults "n_max_adulti" in table "APPARTAMENTO".
This is the table PRENOTAZIONE

```
create table PRENOTAZIONE (
 id_prenotazione serial,
 data_inizio date not null,
 data_fine date not null,
 n_adulti smallint default 1,
 n_bimbi smallint default 0,
 n_neonati smallint default 0,
 n_ospiti_extra smallint default 0,
 appartamento integer not null,
 cliente varchar(255),

 primary key(id_prenotazione),

 foreign key (appartamento)
 references APPARTAMENTO(id_appartamento),

 foreign key (cliente)
 references CLIENTE(email) 
);
```

and this is the table APPARTAMENTO

```
create table APPARTAMENTO (
 id_appartamento serial,
 sconti_mensili real default 0,
 sconti_settimanali real default 0,
 n_camere_letto smallint default 0,
 n_letti smallint default 0,
 n_posti_letto smallint default 0,
 n_bagni smallint default 0,
 orario_check_in time not null,
 orario_check_out time not null,
 n_max_bimbi smallint not null,
 n_max_neonati smallint not null,
 n_max_adulti smallint not null,
 tipo varchar(255) not null,
 descrizione varchar(100) default ' ',
 ospiti_extra smallint default 0,
 cauzione real default 0,
 costi_pulizia real default 0,
 costo_bimbo real default 0,
 costo_adulto real default 0,
 servizio varchar(255),
 indirizzo integer,
 proprietario varchar(255),
 tipologia integer,
 termine_cancellazione smallint default 1,

 primary key(id_appartamento),

 foreign key (indirizzo)
 references INDIRIZZO(id_indirizzo),

 foreign key (termine_cancellazione)
 references TERMINE_DI_CANCELLAZIONE(id_termine),

 foreign key (proprietario)
 references PROPRIETARIO(email),

 foreign key (tipologia)
 references TIPOLOGIA_APPARTAMENTO(id_tipologia),

 foreign key (servizio)
 references SERVIZIO(servizio)
);
```

and this is the check operation i want to do

```
check ((n_adulti > 0) and (n_adulti <= (select n_max_adulti from APPARTAMENTO join PRENOTAZIONE on (id_appartamento = appartamento))))
 and ((n_bimbi >= 0) and (n_bimbi <= (select n_max_bimbi from APPARTAMENTO join PRENOTAZIONE on (id_appartamento = appartamento))
 and ((n_neonati > 0) and (n_neonati <= (select n_max_neonati from APPARTAMENTO join PRENOTAZIONE on (id_appartamento = appartamento)))))
```

but in PostgreSQL  unfortunatly the sub query are not supported... and i need to do this with a trigger.
I looked something here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html
and
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_triggers.htm
but i didn't find what i looking for...
I didn't understand how functions and triggers work together and how can I do this function.

PS: I'm sorry for the name of the tables but I'm Italian. However this database is a school project inspired by Airbnb.
The purpose was to create a similar and simplified database compared to Airbnb.

Comment: I forgot to say, although you can understand that, that appartamento in PRENOTAZIONE references id_appartamento in APPARTAMENTO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a trigger `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON prenotazione FOR EACH ROW` that calls the following PL/pgSQL [trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html):

- Selects `n_max_bimbi`, `n_max_neonati` and `n_max_adulti` from the `appartamento` row that belongs to `NEW.appartamento`.
- If `NEW.n_adulti` is not between 0 and the `n_max_adulti` found above, [raise an appropriate exception](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RAISE). Similar for the others.